# Selection.ClearFormatting can't running

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

**Note: the OP has now revealed that he is trying to do this to a Word document using Excel**

I want to clear the whole word format

```
Sub clearformat()
    Dim MyDialog As FileDialog, vrtSelectedItem As Variant, doc As document
    Dim wApp As Object
    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set MyDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With MyDialog
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "所有 WORD 文件", "*.doc;*.docx", 1
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
        If .Show = -1 Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
            Set doc = wApp.Documents.Open(filename:=vrtSelectedItem, Visible:=False)
            doc.Sections(1).Range.Select
            Selection.ClearFormatting
            doc.Close (True)
            Next
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            MsgBox "clear finished!", vbInformation
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I write the code is in a .xlsm file to control the .docx file.
Object does not support this property and method on "Selection.ClearFormatting"

Comment: I tried your code and I did not get an error on that line. The routine didnt seem to do anything either tho. Maybe include the version of Word you are using.

Comment: why?may be better code?

Comment: no save code in it

Comment: `Selection` probably applies to the active document instead of your `doc` variable. Look into that.

Comment: you means only *.doc not *.docx?

Comment: no, not the file extension, the doc VARIABLE.

Comment: how to use it,I look for it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.clearformatting

Comment: Also, you probably cant use `Selection` when the document is not visible. You are making it not visible when you open it.

Comment: Set doc = Documents.Open(filename:=vrtSelectedItem, Visible:=true)?

Comment: It's display "Object does not support this property and method" on "Selection.ClearFormatting"

Comment: I think it's not the reason

Comment: you are going to have to wait for someone else who may have an idea.

Comment: I also tried your code and it works fine. Maybe you can add on the end save and close `doc.Close (-1)`.  Did you try to run your code on different Word. You can try if it works on empty Word

Comment: Also check in task manages if any Word is running in background and close it. Because you are using  Visible:=False

Comment: I tryed，always the iusse

Comment: the code I write in a xlsm file to control a docx file not in a docx!

Comment: Well that is an important part of your problem, and you did not include that in your question. It works completely differently if you are doing it from Excel.

Comment: I add word.Application,Still not work
I update zhe code

Answer (score 0):

Both Excel and Word have a Selection object. Unless your code specifies which one you are referring to the app that is running the code will take precedence, which in your case is Excel. Change the line of code to:

```
wApp.Selection.ClearFormatting
```